# Is the clause "it's past doubt" archaic?

Tags: archaic-language

From another version of this book I know the clause in boldface can be reworded as "It's certain". I searched the phase "past doubt" in Google but few related results were returned. So I wonder if this usage is a very old-fashioned.

> In a word, however useful medicine well administered may be to us who live in a state of society, **it is still past doubt**, that if, on the one hand, the sick savage destitute of help, has nothing to hope from nature, on the other, he has nothing to fear but from his disease; a circumstance, which often renders his situation preferable to ours.
>
> -- from Rousseau's [“Discourse on Inequality”](http://faculty.wiu.edu/M-Cole/Rousseau.pdf)

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible translation, IMHO.

Comment: @Jim Which version do you recommend?

Comment: I don't have a specific version in mind, I just know enough French to know that's not how I would have translated that passage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [original sentence](http://eet.pixel-online.org/files/etranslation/original/Rousseau%20JJ%20Discours%20sur.pdf) (p.23):

> Enfin, quelque utile que puisse être parmi nous la médecine bien administrée, **il est toujours certain** que si le sauvage malade abandonné à lui-même n'a rien à espérer que de la nature, en revanche il n'a rien à craindre que de son mal, ce qui rend souvent sa situation préférable à la nôtre.

In this case, "il est toujours certain" is translated "it is still past doubt".  Judging by [COHA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) and [Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=past+doubt%2C+beyond+doubt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpast%20doubt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeyond%20doubt%3B%2Cc0) the version with *past* was never popular, but what results I can find for it were mostly in the early 1800s.  I suppose you could call it archaic.

In any case, "past doubt" could be replaced with the more common "beyond doubt", which is a relatively common phrase meaning "certain to be true".  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beyond+doubt?r=66) lists *beyond doubt* as an idiom meaning "with certainty; definitely".

Comment: There's also the fact that *certain* and *certain* are clearly cognates, so I find it odd that any translation wouldn't simply have kept the word as it was! At any rate, +1 :)